# Hash modification issue in hash, replacing value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I would like to get rid of the `value: <value>` key value inside each of the attributes in the hash. And make it like this: `"total_interactions": 493.667`
Below is the incorrect format followed by the expected good format I hope to achieve in json.

```
{
    "3": {
        "total_interactions": {
            "value": 493.667
        },
        "shares": {
            "value": 334
        },
        "comments": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "likes": {
            "value": 159.66666666666666
        },
        "total_documents": 6
    },
    "4": {
        "total_interactions": {
            "value": 701
        },
        "shares": {
            "value": 300
        },
        "comments": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "likes": {
            "value": 401
        },
        "total_documents": 1
    }
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
{
    "3": {
        "total_interactions": 493.6666666666667,
        "shares": 334,
        "comments": 0,
        "likes": 159.66666666666666,
        "total_documents": 6
    },
    "4": {
        "total_interactions": 701,
        "shares": 300,
        "comments": 0,
        "likes": 401,
        "total_documents": 1
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is supposed to do this but is not working. Nothing affected. Not sure what is wrong

```
# the result_hash variable is the first hash with value: <value>
result_hash.each do |hash_item|
            hash_item.each do |key,value_hash|
                if( !value_hash.nil? )
                    value_hash.each do |k,v|
                        hash_item[key] = v
                    end
                end             
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash = {"3"=>{"total_documents"=>6, "comments"=>{"value"=>0}, "total_interactions"=>{"value"=>493.667}, "shares"=>{"value"=>334}, "likes"=>{"value"=>159.666666666667}}, 
        "4"=>{"total_documents"=>1, "comments"=>{"value"=>0}, "total_interactions"=>{"value"=>701}, "shares"=>{"value"=>300}, "likes"=>{"value"=>401}}}

hash.each do |k,v| 
  v.each do |k2, v2|
    if v2.is_a?(Hash) && v2["value"]
      hash[k][k2] = v2["value"]
    end
  end
end
```

after this:

```
hash = {"3"=>{"total_documents"=>6, "comments"=>0, "total_interactions"=>493.667, "shares"=>334, "likes"=>159.666666666667}, 
        "4"=>{"total_documents"=>1, "comments"=>0, "total_interactions"=>701, "shares"=>300, "likes"=>401}}
```

Comment: What is the `hash` at the end? Also do you mean that the hash you are iterating over is my hash `result_hash`? Sorry I'm new to ruby

Comment: In order to work on the hash in your problem, i set it to the variable `hash`.  Then i output it again at the end of the loop just to show that it has indeed changed.  I'll edit my answer to make this a bit more obvious.

Comment: Thank you this works and I understand it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Max Williams' code is perfect for in-place. You can also do this in functional style to get a new, corrected hash:

```
hash.merge(hash) {|k,v| v.merge(v) {|kk,vv| vv.is_a?(Hash) && vv['value'] ? vv['value'] : vv }}
```

Comment: Thank you. I gave this answer as well as Cary's answer credit as it gives me a new way to think about the problem. I selected Max Williams as the final answer to the question since his solution makes it easier for a noob like me to follow. Thank you!

Comment: Generally speaking i think it's better to **not** edit in place (even though that's what i do in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to mutate your initial hash, `h`,you can do this:

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g|
  g[k] = v.each_with_object({}) { |(kk,vv),f|
    f[kk] = (Hash === vv) ? vv[:value] : vv } }
  #=> {:"3"=>{:total_interactions=>493.667,
  #           :shares=>334,
  #           :comments=>0,
  #           :likes=>159.66666666666666,
  #           :total_documents=>6},
  #   :"4"=>{:total_interactions=>701,
  #           :shares=>300,
  #           :comments=>0,
  #           :likes=>401,
  #           :total_documents=>1}}
```

Comment: thank you. I gave this answer as well as Gene's answer credit as it gives me a new way to think about the problem. I selected Max Williams as the final answer to the question since his solution makes it easier for a noob like me to follow. Thank you!